# How to get a simple Onnx model to receive List<double> as input type? I can only make it run with an array of float[]

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, onnx, ml.net

Arrays need to be continuously stored in RAM, which makes it difficult for large input vectors. I want to run my model with a List instead.

I am trying to get my Onnx model to run on a List instad of a float[]. How can I do this?

Below is some of my code. This is just for context, as I don't think it is necessary for the question to make sense:

```
private void onneximport()
        {
            MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

            var onnxPredictionPipeline = GetPredictionPipeline(mlContext);
            var onnxPredictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<OnnxInput, OnnxOutput>(onnxPredictionPipeline);

            var testInput = new OnnxInput
            {
                X = new float[] { 1, 1 }
            };

            var prediction = onnxPredictionEngine.Predict(testInput);
            var pred = prediction.y;
            Console.WriteLine($"Predicted: {prediction.y.First()}");

        }
        static ITransformer GetPredictionPipeline(MLContext mlContext)
        {
            var inputColumns = new string[]{ "float_input" };
            var outputColumns = new string[] { "variable" };

            var onnxPredictionPipeline =
                mlContext
                    .Transforms
                    .ApplyOnnxModel(
                        outputColumnNames: outputColumns,
                        inputColumnNames: inputColumns,
                        ONNX_MODEL_PATH);

            var emptyDv = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new OnnxInput[] { });

            return onnxPredictionPipeline.Fit(emptyDv);
        }
```

These are the input and output classes:

```
public class OnnxInput
{
    [VectorType(2)]
    [ColumnName("float_input")]
    public float[] X { get; set; }
}

public class OnnxOutput
{
    [ColumnName("variable")]
    public float[] y { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how the model was generated, on python google colab:

```
!pip install skl2onnx

from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import numpy as np
from skl2onnx import convert_sklearn
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import FloatTensorType

n_samples, n_features = 5, 2
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = [[0, 0],
     [1, 1],
     [2, 2],
     [3, 3],
     [4, 4]]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
regr = make_pipeline(SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.2))
regr.fit(X, y)

from google.colab import files

initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, 2]))]
onnx = convert_sklearn(regr, initial_types=initial_type)
with open("onnxModel.onnx", "wb") as f:
    f.write(onnx.SerializeToString())


files.download('onnxModel.onnx')
```

Simply changing

Comment: What do you think the underlying storage for a List is?

Comment: @DavidL as I understand it, it doesn't need a continous allocation in the ram. Even if it uses as much/more space than an array, it can be distributed across different sections of the ram. Or so I think.

Comment: @thelsales which part of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0 "The List<T> class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It implements the IList<T> generic interface by *using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required*." made you think so?

Comment: It is backed by a single array and is dynamically resized as additional capacity is required: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs.